# How to create a news ticker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'd like to have a news ticker that scrolls from right to left that is easy to add a delete items.

It'd be ideal if I could use jQuery or raw JavaScript if I have to.

Is there a jQuery plugin or a way I can get a news ticker?

After research, I've noticed that a lot of them scroll from top to bottom and not from right to left.

The point of the news ticker is that it's easy to add or remove items, and when you hover, the ticker stops and then resumes when the mouse is not over it.

## Update

I've just found liScroll - http://www.gcmingati.net/wordpress/wp-content/lab/jquery/newsticker/jq-liscroll/scrollanimate.html

http://htmlmarquee.com/ looks pretty good too

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you need a functionality like a Ticker, maybe Left to Right or Top to Bottom, you could simple use the html `marquee` tag. Use [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) or [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) to update it's content dynamically as you feed comfortable.

You can also alter its motion behavior with `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` events, like

```html
    <marquee behavior="scroll" direction="right" 
        onmouseover="this.stop();" 
        onmouseout="this.start();">
            Hover to stop!
    </marquee>
```

You can play with this at [htmlmarquee.com](http://www.htmlmarquee.com/). Check it.
You can see other available options for motion control [here](http://www.htmlcodes.me/marquees/stop-marquee.cfm).

Comment: I'll have to give that a try. Thanks!

Comment: According to MDN "This feature is obsolete. Although it may still work in some browsers, its use is discouraged since it could be removed at any time. Try to avoid using it."https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee

Comment: @Mehmet what's the alternative?

Comment: CSS animation or ready newsticker plugins.I use this one http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-simple-news-ticker--net-6331

Comment: htmlmarquee.com is broken (Gives a 403 Forbidden right now). And the `<marquee>` tag is [marked as obsolete in HTML5](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html)

Answer (score 5):

Though the `<marquee>`-element, as suggested by mtk, will work in most browsers, it is not standard HTML and should not be used, if standards-compliance is an issue. You should then use the [appropriate CSS](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-marquee/)-styles!

You can then put your content in almost any HTML-element and just "marquee" it around as you like.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [jQuery News Ticker](http://www.jquerynewsticker.com/)?

Comment: It's slightly different that what I'd like. jQuery News Ticker starts typing the news, I'd like if they were to scroll from right to left.